# JSON response into HTML

Tags: ajax, jquery

Could you please help me in forming the DIV block(HTML) for the response which i got in JSON format.

JSON format: `[{"REL_NAME" : " 999999999","SO" : "","U_ID" : "105"}]`

Snippet:

```
function ServiceSucceeded(result) {
  $('#accNo12').empty();
  if (DataType == "json") {
  $('#accNo12').append("<div id=\"Search\" class=\"results\">"+
  "<span id=\"lb\">Account No:"+result.U_ID+"</span></div>"+
  "<label>RelMgr: </label>"+
  "<span id=\"RID\">"+result.REL_NAME +"</span><br />"+
    "<label>Off ID: </label><span id=\"OffId\">"+ result.SO+"</span><br/>");
         }
  }
```

As of now i am getting the output values as undefined.
Appreciate if you could help

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
function ServiceSucceeded(result) {
  $('#accNo12').empty();
  if (DataType == "json") {
    result = result[0];
    ...
```

basically, your result object is inside an array. alternatively you can use `result[0].U_ID` instead of `result.U_ID`

Comment: it's one or the other. what is the output of console.log(result) in the console? as said in the other answer, you may need to use `result = $.parseJSON(result)` if the ajax dataType is not json (if left unset, jquery will recognize it as json thou)

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem here is that you don't parse the JSON data
Add this at the beginning of your function,

```
result = jQuery.parseJSON(result);
```

Comment: I am getting the JSON data in proper format, i check the result in alert box

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are checking for an inexistent DataType. I fiddled around and here are the results:

```
html:
<div id='accNo12'>hello</div>

javascript:
function ServiceSucceeded(result,DataType) {
alert(DataType);
$('#accNo12').empty();
if (DataType == "json") {
    $('#accNo12').append("<div id=\"Search\" class=\"results\">"+
        "<span id=\"lb\">Account No:"+result.U_ID+"</span></div>"+
        "<label>RelMgr: </label>"+
        "<span id=\"RID\">"+result.REL_NAME +"</span><br />"+
        "<label>Off ID: </label><span id=\"OffId\">"+ result.SO+"</span><br/>");
    }
}

$(document).ready( function () {
    ServiceSucceeded(jQuery.parseJSON('{"REL_NAME" : " 999999999","SO" : "","U_ID" : "105"}'),'json');
});

result:
Account No:105
RelMgr: 999999999
Off ID:
```